# Django template reverse url resolution without creating group for variable

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I want to create urls like this;

```
.../film/slug-of-the-film/id-of-film
.../film/id-of-film
```

example;

```
../film/fight-club/1040
../film/1040
```

two links are same.

when I do like this;

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+/)?(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.summary, name="film_summary")
```

I can reverse url from template with `{% url film_summary film.slug film.id %}`

I dont use slug. It is just for readability. So I try something like that;

```
url(r'^(?:[-\w]+/)?(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.summary, name="film_summary")
```

but I can't reverse this from template. Is there any way to do that?

Except solutions like this; `/film/{{film.slug}}/{{film.id}}`

Actually I don't know is it necessary to do like that. I just aimed to don't add a parameter to view function that I won't use.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I would handle them as separate urls. That also simplifies the regexp for human readers.

```
url(r'^(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.summary, name="film_summary"),
url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+/)?(?P<id>[0-9]+)/$', views.summary)
```